# Display random images along with links and without duplicate images

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi i try to display random images with links and without image duplication. The code that i have shows only one image. But actually i want to display three images separately without duplicates on page refresh. Help me to get this done. Thanks in advance.

```js
var total_images = 7;
var image = document.getElementById('banner');
var random_number = Math.floor((Math.random() * total_images));
var random_img = [];

random_img[0] = '<a href="https://cdn.paperindex.com/banner/advertisement/1.jpeg"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/banner/advertisement/1.jpeg"></a>';
random_img[1] = '<a href="https://cdn.paperindex.com/banner/advertisement/2.jpeg"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/banner/advertisement/2.jpeg"></a>';
random_img[2] = '<a href="https://cdn.paperindex.com/banner/advertisement/3.jpeg"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/banner/advertisement/3.jpeg"></a>';
random_img[3] = '<a href="https://cdn.paperindex.com/banner/advertisement/4.jpeg"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/banner/advertisement/4.jpeg"></a>';
random_img[4] = '<a href="https://cdn.paperindex.com/banner/advertisement/5.jpeg"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/banner/advertisement/5.jpeg"></a>';
random_img[5] = '<a href="https://cdn.paperindex.com/banner/advertisement/6.jpeg"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/banner/advertisement/6.jpeg"></a>';
random_img[6] = '<a href="https://cdn.paperindex.com/banner/advertisement/7.jpeg"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/banner/advertisement/7.jpeg"></a>';

image.innerHTML = random_img[random_number];
```

```css
#banner a img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can put your numbers in an array and test with `indexOf` if it already exists (note that all that can be done in a loop to be more generic, just beware that array indexes start with 0, don't forget to subtract 1 if your names start by 1):

```js
var total_images = 7;
var image1 = document.getElementById('banner1');
var image2 = document.getElementById('banner2');
var image3 = document.getElementById('banner3');
var random_numbers = [];
var random_number;
var random_img = [];

random_img[0] = '<a href="https://cdn.paperindex.com/banner/advertisement/1.jpeg"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/banner/advertisement/1.jpeg"></a>';
random_img[1] = '<a href="https://cdn.paperindex.com/banner/advertisement/2.jpeg"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/banner/advertisement/2.jpeg"></a>';
random_img[2] = '<a href="https://cdn.paperindex.com/banner/advertisement/3.jpeg"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/banner/advertisement/3.jpeg"></a>';
random_img[3] = '<a href="https://cdn.paperindex.com/banner/advertisement/4.jpeg"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/banner/advertisement/4.jpeg"></a>';
random_img[4] = '<a href="https://cdn.paperindex.com/banner/advertisement/5.jpeg"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/banner/advertisement/5.jpeg"></a>';
random_img[5] = '<a href="https://cdn.paperindex.com/banner/advertisement/6.jpeg"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/banner/advertisement/6.jpeg"></a>';
random_img[6] = '<a href="https://cdn.paperindex.com/banner/advertisement/7.jpeg"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/banner/advertisement/7.jpeg"></a>';

while(random_numbers.length < 3){
  random_number = Math.floor((Math.random() * total_images));
  if(random_numbers.indexOf(random_number) < 0){
    random_numbers.push(random_number);
  }
}

image1.innerHTML = random_img[random_numbers[0]];
image2.innerHTML = random_img[random_numbers[1]];
image3.innerHTML = random_img[random_numbers[2]];
```

```css
#banner1 a img, #banner2 a img, #banner3 a img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner1"></div>
<div id="banner2"></div>
<div id="banner3"></div>
```